# IE9 script is not run until I open console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a page with JS code. When I open this page in IE9, the code isn't run. However, when I open console with F12 and reload the page the script starts executing. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the JS error icon on the status bar. You probably are getting something about how `console.log` doesn't exist because it doesn't until you open the developer tools (in IE).

A fix for this in your code would be to check for the existence of `console.log` and if it doesn't exist, create one.

```
if (typeof console !== 'object' || typeof console.log !== 'function') {
    console.log = function (arg) {
        //now you can alert the argument or do whatever even when console.log isn't natively supported
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything starting with `console` actually, though the vast majority of the time, that will be `console.log`